# Jquery ajax in iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax

Can anyone tell me how to use Jquery Ajax in Iphone app. development ?
Sample codes are appreciated .

Thank you.

Comment: You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: Are you talking about making jquery ajax calls in a web page access via an iPhone or a full on iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine it would be the same as normal AJAX development.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    success: function( data )
    {
        console.log( data );
    }
});
```